# get video metadata with carrierwave video

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, video, ruby-on-rails-3.2, carrierwave

I'm using [carrierwave-video](https://github.com/rheaton/carrierwave-video) gem to transcode the videos.

With this code I can get the video `file_size` and `content_type`:

```
class VideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::Video
  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
  .
  .
  .
  process :set_content_type
  process :save_content_type_and_size_in_model 

  def save_content_type_and_size_in_model
    model.content_type = file.content_type if file.content_type
    model.file_size = file.size
  end
end
```

I would like to know these video data:

```
width, height, duration, bit_rate, checksum
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/rheaton/carrierwave-video#dynamic-configuration Dynamic Configuration shows you can do a movie.height . Width should also work. Looking through the code did not see ruby interface to get the checksum and bitrate details. Worth a pull request IMO

Comment: Can you paste a example and make an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out this gem instead https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg

It does all you asked for.